# How to set a size of array from Scanner object

Tags: java

How to get the size of an array from a passed object. In the code below, I created an object with size of 10 because the passed Scanner object has 10 lines of objects. But what if 100 objects are passed? 1000? How to handle that? For example:

```
public static Exam[] readAllExams(Scanner s) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    {

        String firstName = "";
        String lastName = "";
        int ID = 0;
        String examType = "";
        char examTypeCasted;
        int score = 0;

        int index = 0;

        Exam[] object = new Exam[10];

        while(s.hasNext())
        {
            //Returns firtsName and lastName 
            firstName = s.next();
            lastName = s.next();

            //Returns ID number
            if(s.hasNextInt())
            {
                ID = s.nextInt();
            }
            else 
                s.next();

            //Returns examType which is 'M' or 'F'
            examType = s.next();
            examTypeCasted = examType.charAt(0);

            if(s.hasNextInt())
            {
                score = s.nextInt();
            }

             object[index] = new Exam(firstName, lastName, ID, examTypeCasted, score);
            //System.out.println();
            index++;
        }
        readExam(s);
        return object;
```

Comment: Can you use an `ArrayList`?

Comment: You cannot resize an array in Java once it is created. You only option is to create a new array and "forget" the old one (since GC will take care of it for you)

Comment: W/o ArrayList! How to handle that?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an array, use a data structure that grows dynamically:

```
ArrayList<Exam> object = new ArrayList<Exam>();
```

Then change:

```
object[index] = new Exam(firstName, lastName, ID, examTypeCasted, score);
```

To:

```
object.add( new Exam(firstName, lastName, ID, examTypeCasted, score) );
```

You'll also need to change your return type to `ArrayList<Exam>`, and don't forget to import it:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

Comment: How to do that w/o ArrayList? @Kacy Raye

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use an `ArrayList` you can change your code to look like this:

```
if (index == object.length) {
        Exam objectTmp[] = new Exam[object.length * 2];
        System.arraycopy(object, 0, objectTmp, 0, object.length);
        object = objectTmp;
        objectTmp = null;
} 

object[index] = new Exam(firstName, lastName, ID, examTypeCasted, score);
```

The strategy is to just double the length of your `object` array if it is full.